# Best models to relate a frequent point process and a rare point process

Tags: logistic, vector-autoregression, point-process, hawkes-process

I want to relate two processes and understand their cause-and-effect relationship.

The first process is a point process with frequent occurrences (more than 90%) and has support [0,1] and truncated Exponential distribution, the second process is a point process with rare occurrences (less than 0.01%) and support [0,$\infty$] and Exponential distribution.

A) If both processes were such as the first process I would discard the non-occurrences or put them to zero and estimate a VAR model (results would be biased but the bias would be limited), but I can't do this with the second process because I would remain with too few observations or too many zeros (it already has occurrences where the value of the observation is zero and they are not the same thing as a non-occurrence, I would bias the results too much).

B) If both processes were such as the second process I would estimate a Hawkes model, but it is not appropriate for the first process because Hawkes models are not suitable for frequent processes. I tried, and indeed the outcome is an unstable process (spectral radius of the branching matrix not smaller than one) and I think this is due to the too many occurrences of the continuous process. Actually I have one frequent process and two rare processes but I tried to make the question simple. The estimated branching matrix is:

0.35 0.25 0.0001

0.20 0.34 0.0002

-0.25 -4.64 1.01

and the resulting spectral radius is 1.01.

C) I estimated a logistic regression linking the probability of the occurrences of the first process to the occurrences of the second process, but in this way I can't consider the effect of the values of the second process.

D) I estimated a logistic regression linking the probability of the occurrences of the first process to the values of the second process, putting to zero the non-occurrences of the second process, but the results are obviously biased as I explained above.

E) I estimated a logistic regression linking the probability of the occurrences of the second process to the occurrences of the first process, but in this way I can't consider the effect of the values of the first process.

F) I estimated a logistic regression linking the probability of the occurrences of the second process to the values of the first process, putting to zero the non-occurrences of the first process, the results should be biased but not too much.

So far, it seems to me that, perhaps except for point F), all ways I considered are too problematic. I would appreciate suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by "frequent process"? I assume this means you have discretised the process into bins and 90% of the bins contain an event. Either way, the branching parameter of the Hawkes process relates only to the excitation effect, not to the overall rate of events, so I wonder if your estimation of a Hawkes process could be improved.

Comment: Yes, for the "frequent process" more than 90% of the observations contain an event. I edited the question adding the estimated branching matrix. Do you suggest a Hawkes model is the most appropriate way to proceed and that I should check (again) my estimation?

Answer (score 1):

The model you describe in F) has been used previously in the literature (see my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/511416/135759)). It can be seen as a discretised version of the Hawkes process, where the conditional intensity function is the probability of an event happening in a bin at time $t$, passed through a logit link (just as in logistic regression).

From your description of the problem, it seems that you have binary (discretised) data from the start. In that case, fitting the binary autoregression model I linked to is the most sensible approach. The Hawkes model data are the event times, not the event counts, and this might explain the unstable solution you have found with spectral radius greater than one.

The marks (values) of the past can be incorporated on top of the times into the logistic specification by adding extra linear terms. This is similar to the marked Hawkes process.

Comment: From how the model you mention is written, on the right-hand-side of the logit there are the binary variables x and y and not their values, so it resembles points C) and E) of my question (I didn't specify that I employed various lags for the explanatory variables). Then you suggest adding the values, similarly to points D) and F). Maybe employing the values and the binary variables in the same logistic regression is something to consider, however it seems you agree with my logit approach, at least in line of principle. Am I correct?

Comment: With regard to "The Hawkes model data are the event times, not the event counts, and this might explain the unstable solution...", I think I correctly estimated the Hawkes model but it was useful to mention that.

Comment: @FrancescoVe, I agree that it is more general in that you would be adding more values; on the other hand, the marked Hawkes process also regresses in a "linear" way on the past times *and* marks. The logistic link should stay there either way. Regarding your second point, I found that estimating Hawkes processes from data can lead surprisingly often to "unstable" processes with the spectral radius $>1$. A variety of factors can lead to this, such as edge effects, starting conditions, etc.