# Implementing Granger causality for 2 binary event timeseries

Tags: time-series, forecasting, binary-data, granger-causality

I am trying to understand how to implement granger causality to binary valued timeseries data (0/1). I only found one other question on here at [Granger Causality Analog for Binary Time Series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504758/granger-causality-analog-for-binary-time-series), but the answer is difficult to comprehend for implementation. I couldn't understand if I need to transform my 0/1 timeseries to start with. I do not have a strong math background which makes the answer harder to understand.

Comment: What was the other answer?

Comment: Hi. I didn't have enough reputation to post on this original similar question. So posting the link here. Thanks
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504758/granger-causality-analog-for-binary-time-series

Comment: That looks like a fairly complete answer. Your questions looks like a duplicate of it. Perhaps you could rephrase yours to address the particular details which you find difficult? Perhaps that would be more than one question, but it is OK to open several new threads.