# Granger causality test for interleaved and irregular time series

Tags: time-series, granger-causality

I am very new to time series analysis. Please help me if the following analysis and interpretation are wrong. Thank you!
I have a time series with two different events, as in the following illustration.
[image]
Each blue block generates a continuous measurement, and its length represents time duration. Every red dot produces a binary state. 
I would like to know 1) whether the continuous measurement in blue blocks Granger causes the binary state in red dots and 2) whether the binary state in red dots Granger causes the continuous measurement in blue blocks. Because the two events occurred at different times, I rearranged their relationship:
[image]
The red arrow may answer the first question.

[image]
And this red arrow may answer the second one. 
However, I wasn't sure if this rearrangement was valid, especially since I arbitrarily moved the preceding or following red dot events to the same time points as the blue blocks. Can I achieve the purpose I want through this analysis? Or maybe Granger causality in this case is the wrong starting point for what I want?

Comment: I'm very curious, did you find an answer to this question? 
This question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504758/granger-causality-analog-for-binary-time-series) discusses applying a Granger causality algorithm called ALARM to binary data, but yours has both binary and continuous data so I'm unsure how applicable this would be.